# Why do some applications need a proxy to run on certain networks?

Tags: proxy

This is something I have always had trouble understanding. Why and when do I need a proxy? At work I am trying to run the eclipse windows installer, but it says I need to configure a proxy, also Maven does not download dependencies and I believe I need to configure a proxy for Maven too. My question is why? At home I don't need to do this, why does this not just work at my workplace? What is the difference in the two situations?

Comment: I expect that your workplace network is configured to require Internet access through the company proxy server. This enables them to have better control over how company network resources are used. As for the details you would need to contact the company IT staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workplaces generally force you through a proxy server so it's administratively simpler to track web (or other) traffic and enforce IT policies, such as

- Acceptable use (blocking or tracking visits to inappropriate sites)
- Security (blocking visits to malicious sites, or keeping logs for future investigation of security incidents)

If your workplace has the right networking equipment and configuration in place, they can actually make the proxy [transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) (i.e., it just works -- you don't have to do any configuration on your side).

Generally, you pay for home ISP service with the understanding that it's not their business to tell you what you should or shouldn't do, so they either don't run you through a proxy, or at least they make it transparent.

Comment: When is it not transparent, like why can't I just use dockerhub, github, maven and others just out of the box when behind a proxy?

Comment: You're behind a firewall that won't route you out to the Internet. The only way out is via the proxy.

Comment: Is there any solution? I am having trouble configuring the proxy settings for each application, so far unsuccessful on every level.

Comment: You'd have to check with your local IT people on what proxy settings to use. There's not really any way around that if you're going to use that network... If you want application-specific help, you'll need to be more specific about what issues you're running into.

Comment: Eclipse->Marketplace doesn't work, Maven->Doesn't connect to repository, UbuntuVB->Can't update Linux Packages, Docker->Can't connect to dockerhub. Seriously like every single Dev tool which access some repo or something does not work. Even when I try and add proxy settings, although I am not sure if I have the correct proxy URI. But I solved my problem by getting a new phone plan with 22GB data a month lol, thanks anyway.

Comment: It's just because I picked a windows laptop. All my colleagues have Macs and they 4G cards which are unlocked, but my one is locked to my company's group policy, anyway problem solved and new iPhone haha I accepted your answer though, I can't get ITS to help me, it's a big corp nothing I can do.